# urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused in a very simple script

Tags: python, ssl, https, urllib2

I already checked if proxy settings were enabled, reset winsock, uninstall firewall and antivirus, and I still get the same error message, but if I type the url in Firefox or IE it works just fine. Thanks for any help

Here is the script:

```
import urllib2
import ssl

gcontext = ssl._create_unverified_context()
url = 'https://192.168.1.1:8000/cgi-bin/login.html'
html = urllib2.urlopen(url=url,context=gcontext).read()    
print html
```

and here is the traceback:

```
File "get_url.py", line 6, in <module>
    f = urllib2.urlopen("https://192.168.1.1:8000/cgi-bin/login.html",context=gcontext, timeout=3000)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 435, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 548, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 467, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 407, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 654, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 429, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 447, in _open
    '_open', req)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 407, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1241, in https_open
    context=self._context)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1198, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>
```

Comment: Your code is right , issue is your URL opener unable to connect this URL Port , You can Try with Another URL eg. url = " http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_examples.asp" That you get URL Page Data(source code).

Comment: Can you give a try requests.get('url', verify=False) ? i like using requests than httplib or urllib

Comment: Thanks for the answers .  I tried my code again with several pages with the default SSL port (443) and it works, but if I type a :8000 (even if the port is open and I can access the site using Firefox) I can't connect using this script.